# Spring webflow - how to pass the session in evaluate expression?

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm using spring webflow, but I need to access my HttpSession in a method that's accessed using a transition ==> evaluate expression. (so in the xml file containing my flow)
So far I've yet to find a way to actually pass it to my method. I've taken a look at the flowrequestcontext but so far I haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you don't need to pass it as soon as you pass the RequestContext. You can try this:

```
public class MyAction extends MultiAction{      
    public Event myMethod(RequestContext context){
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getNativeRequest()).getSession();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any reference for the same implementation @vliolios thanks

Answer (score 6):

to insert object (e.g. from flowScope) into session this worked for me:

```
<evaluate expression="externalContext.sessionMap.put('attributeName', flowScope.myObject)"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar need to access the `HttpSession` in a flow. Here's how I did it:

First, take a look at the `externalContext` special EL variable:

[externalContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#el-variable-externalContext)

It gives you one of these:

`org.springframework.webflow.context.ExternalContext`

The `ExternalContext` interface provides a method called `getNativeRequest()`, which should return to you an `HttpRequest` object. (in weblflow 2.0.x at least)

Here is the javadoc:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/context/ExternalContext.html#getNativeRequest()

So, that means you should able to craft an expression using something like this:

`<evaluate expression="externalContext.nativeRequest.session" result="flowScope.information"/>`

As a simple test, you can use an expression like this:

`expression="externalContext.nativeRequest.session.id"`

to pass your session id to a method.

Of course you can use similar EL to pass the session to methods etc.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<set name="flowRequestContext.externalContext.sessionMap.myId" value="myObject.getId()" />
```

On the client:

```
Long id = (Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("myId");
```

Hope it helps!