# FlowScope get clear on page refresh

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, cas, spring-webflow-2

Based on my application requirements, I have to declare some variables for login process(say, failed login attempts).

hence, using

> context.getFlowScope().put("count", ++count);

seems to be the solution. But after refreshing the page, using F5 or even in worse case ctrl+F5, the variables get reset and bind to null.

So, what should I do for having consistent,request-bind attributes for every single request.

note that I am forced to use

> org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the count variable in the session instead. See the following examples

[Spring webflow - how to pass the session in evaluate expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913062/spring-webflow-how-to-pass-the-session-in-evaluate-expression)